# parse server auto shutdown with validation failed error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

i am trying to send email by using parse cloud code, parse javascript sdk and mailgun. Here is my cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendEmail", {useMasterKey: true}, function(request,response){

    var api = "xxxx";
    var domain = "xxxx";
    var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({
        apiKey: api, 
        domain: domain
    });

    var mail = {
        from: request.params.email,
        to: "someemail@email.com",
        subject: request.params.name,
        text: request.params.message
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(mail, function (error, body) {
        if (error) {
            inspect(error, 'mailgun sendError');
        } else {
            inspect(body, 'Successfully send email to "' + toEmail + '"');
        }
    });

});
```

and here is my client code:

```
Parse.initialize("app-id");
Parse.serverURL = 'example.com/parse';

var SendEmail= Parse.Object.extend("SendEmail");
var sendEmail= new SendEmail();

$("#someform").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data ={};
        data.name = $("#name").val();
        data.email = $("#email").val();
        data.message = $("#message").val();

    sendEmail.set("name", data.name);
    sendEmail.set("email", data.email);
    sendEmail.set("message", data.message);
    console.log(data);

        sendEmail.save(data, {
            success:function(result){
                console.log("success saved!");
                Parse.Cloud.run('sendEmail', data).then(function(result) {
                    console.log("Success");
                },  function(error){
                    console.error("Fail");
                });
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.error("something is wrong!");
            }
        });
});
```

The data saved in my parse server, mailgun logs show status 200 and email was successfully been sent but parse server auto shut down every time and when I restart the parse server, logs showed "Error handling request: ParseError { code: 142, message: 'Validation failed.' }". I can still receive the message and save the data but unable to get logs by removing the useMasterKey. I have tried to create another new parse server and it ended up the same. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: are you using Pm2?

Comment: no, my parse server running on openshift.